# Application is not opening in MacOS Sierra Firefox 56.0. Only browser opens then it time outs

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, macos-sierra

OS : MacOS Sierra

Browser: Firefox 56.0

Selenium Server standalone 3.6.jar

Browser Driver : geckodriver 0.19

```
public class DemoTestNg {

  @Test
  public void test1() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "/Users/suresh/eclipse-workspace/SeleniumProjec/drivers/geckodriver");
      WebDriver fd = new FirefoxDriver();
      fd.get("https://www.facebook.com");
      WebElement email = fd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']"));
      email.sendKeys("hhdvchsdvhdsg");
      WebElement pwd = fd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pass']"));
      pwd.sendKeys("cdsjcjdsvbjd");
      WebElement loginBtn = fd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='u_0_2']"));
      loginBtn.click();
  }
}
```

The Error log below:

```
FAILED: test1
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
    Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
    System info: host: 'IndiaWebs-MBP.dhcp.indiadev.lexmark.com', ip: '10.195.25.218', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.5', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
    Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:112)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.start(XpiDriverService.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:217)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:140)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
        at selePack.DemoTestNg.test1(DemoTestNg.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
    Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:37503/hub/status] to be available after 45007 ms
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:110)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:147)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
        ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "/Users/suresh/eclipse-workspace/SeleniumProjec/drivers/geckodriver");
```

To :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/suresh/eclipse-workspace/SeleniumProjec/drivers/geckodriver");
```

Comment: Before using **webdriver.firefox.marionette** , i tried with **webdriver.gecko.driver**. When using **webdriver.firefox.marionette** at least browser open the nothing happens but when using **webdriver.gecko.driver**, even browser is not opening and it ends up with error

Comment: Can you revert back to "webdriver.gecko.driver", update the question with your exact code block & error stack trace? Take a system restart before you start the execution.